# Tap test times out

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, tap

I try to perform a Diffie Hellman Key agreement:

```
Test.test('testDh', (t) => {
  const k1 = createSelfKey();
  const k2 = createSelfKey(k1.dh.getPrime(), k1.dh.getGenerator());

  const k1Secret = k1.dh.computeSecret(k2.keys);
  const k2Secret = k2.dh.computeSecret(k1.keys);

  t.equal(k1Secret.toString('hex'), k2Secret.toString('hex'));
  t.end();
});
```

Using the following function:

```
const createSelfKey = (p, g) => {
  let returnVal = null;
  if (_.isNumber(p) && _.isNumber(g)) {
    returnVal = { dh: crypto.createDiffieHellman(p, g) };
  } else {
    returnVal = { dh: crypto.createDiffieHellman(2048) };
  }
  returnVal.keys = returnVal.dh.generateKeys();
  return returnVal;
};
```

But for some reason the test times out. Do you know how I can raise the limit for timeout?

```
test/keygenTests.js ................................... 1/2 31s
  not ok timeout!
    expired: test/keygenTests.js

test/participantTest.js ............................... 1/1
total ................................................. 2/3


  2 passing (31s)
  1 failing

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the tests not to timeout by modifying your `package.json` script like that:

```
 "scripts": {
    //Other scripts do there
    "test": "tap --no-timeout test/*.js",
  },
```

As you can see you can pass the parameter `--no-timeout` in order to your test not times out at all, usefull in testing computation-heavy code.